# How to invoke Spark functions (with arguments) from applications.properties(config file)?

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, config, typesafe-config

So, I have a typesafe config file named `application.properties` which contains certain values like:

```
dev.execution.mode = local
dev.input.base.dir = /Users/debaprc/Documents/QualityCheck/Data
dev.schema.lis = asin StringType,subs_activity_date DateType,marketplace_id DecimalType
```

I have used these values as Strings in my Spark code like:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val props = ConfigFactory.load()
    val envProps = props.getConfig("dev")

    val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("DataQualityCheckSession")
      .config("spark.master", envProps.getString("execution.mode"))
      .getOrCreate()
```

Now I have certain functions defined in my spark code (func1, func2, etc...). I want to specify which functions are to be called, along with the respective arguments, in my `application.properties` file. Something like this:

```
dev.functions.lis = func1,func2,func2,func3
dev.func1.arg1.lis = arg1,arg2
dev.func2.arg1.lis = arg3,arg4,arg5
dev.func2.arg2.lis = arg6,arg7,arg8
dev.func3.arg1.lis = arg9,arg10,arg11,arg12
```

Now, once I specify these, what do I do in Spark, to call the functions with the provided arguments? Or do I need to specify the functions and arguments in a different way?

Comment: I doubt it could be possible, and that would be a terrible idea

Comment: @cchantep what would you do to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @cchantep the approach seems wrong. But if you still want to do something like that, I would decouple the function names in the properties file from the actual functions/methods in your code.

I have tried this and worked fine:

```scala
def function1(args: String): Unit = {
  println(s"func1 args: $args")
}

def function2(args: String): Unit = {
  println(s"func2 args: $args")
}

val functionMapper: Map[String, String => Unit] = Map(
  "func1" -> function1,
  "func2" -> function2
)

val args = "arg1,arg2"

functionMapper("func1")(args)
functionMapper("func2")(args)
```

Output:

```
func1 args: arg1,arg2
func2 args: arg1,arg2
```

Edited: Simpler approach with output example.

Comment: Your method is giving 2 errors: for the functionMapper code, I get an error `missing argument list for method function1 in object MyApp`. Also for invocation, I get the error, `'Object' does not take parameters`

Comment: I have edited the code to provide an easier fully working example. please try that suggestion

Comment: This works fine if all functions `function1, function2 etc...` all have the same number and type of parameters. And the same return type as well.
What if function1 takes 2 parameters (string, string), but function2 takes 1 parameter(string)?

Comment: You can pass the full args string, and split it up inside each function to parse the number of arguments you need

Comment: Yep, that's what I did. Thanks, I'm upvoting this

Comment: could you please accept the solution if it has resolved your question? That will help my reputation and I would really appreciate it :)